Concatenate the strings to text in a range if the text length is less than 7
I have a range that contains some text. Each text has a length of 6 (ex: "301.12", "301. 84", 301.12") and 7 (ex: "301.134", "301.446", "217.319"). How to add 1 string to a text with a length of 6 so that the length of the text becomes 7 in VBA Excel?
Text in the range:
301.12
301.84
301.12
301.134
301.446
217.319

Expected text:
301.12X
301.84X
301.12X
301.134
301.446
217.319


In you case you may try-
Sub AddText()
Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Range("A1:A7")
        If Len(rng) < 7 Then
            rng = rng & "x"
        End If
    Next

End Sub

If your text less than 6 character length and you want to make them 7 character then use-
For Each rng In Range("A1:A7")
    If Len(rng) < 7 Then
        rng = Left(rng & "xxxxxxx", 7)
    End If
Next


great answer, sir. thank you for advice
